# Using a script to update all columns in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

The other day I asked a similar question relating to column titles. Now I'm wandering how something like

```
update table1
set column1=REPLACE(column1, '"','')

update table2
set column2=REPLACE(column2, '"','')

update table3
set column3=REPLACE(column2, '"','')
```

might be achieved. I'm sure this will be something involving `sys.objects` or `information_schema.columns` something along those lines (whatever the green keywords in SSMS are called).

Would this have to be done with a cursor?

Comment: You should avoid cursors. What are you exactly trying to update? The column names or the values inside the columns?

Comment: @njk so i've heard, quite vociferously.

Comment: If you're referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122395/removing-quotes-added-to-column-names-from-excel-import-sql-server-2008) have you attempted to generalize the same technique of generating code from metadata to your current tasks? If so, what precise problems are you having?

Comment: @njk you cannot say to avoid cursors, there are times that they are in fact needed to perform certain operations.

Comment: @bluefeet You're right. I was more or less trying to say that the OP shouldn't use cursors for this solution.

Comment: @Pondlife the SQL books that i've been through weren't vendor-specific and never mentioned things like `information.schema`.  i don't even know the correct nomenclature for them and the things like `sys.tables`.  this was a way to get myself accustomed to seeing some of these commands in use

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are after but something like the following might help or at least point you in the right direction.

```
    declare @sqlCmd as varchar(max)
    set @sqlCmd = ''

    select @sqlCmd = 'set ' + column_name  + ' = replace(' + column_name + ',''"'','''')'
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME = 'table1'

   set @sqlCmd = 'update table1 ' + @sqlCmd
   print @sqlCmd
   exec(@sqlCmd)
```

Comment: this is more along the lines of what i was looking for: a step in the right direction.