# Rename column returning error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I tried using [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13126676/78522) to rename badly named columns in SQL Server. The generated statement seems correct:
`EXEC sp_rename '[TBL_TAXREPORTtestxxx].["InsertedOn"]', 'InsertedOn', 'COLUMN'`

however that gives me the following error:

```
Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 266
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Try including the schema name.

Comment: Works for me; `select 1 as '"InsertedOn"' into TBL_TAXREPORTtestxxx; EXEC sp_rename '[TBL_TAXREPORTtestxxx].["InsertedOn"]', 'InsertedOn', 'COLUMN'; select * from TBL_TAXREPORTtestxxx` sure the name is correct? Are executing against the correct DB/schema?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: the schema name was indeed the missing point, thanks. Can you make it an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** You can try to check if you are running the query in the correct database.

**Option 2:** If yes then try this:

```
EXEC sp_rename 
@objname = 'TBL_TAXREPORTtestxxx."[InsertedOn]"',   --or @objname = 'TBL_TAXREPORTtestxxx."InsertedOn"'
@newname = 'InsertedOn', 
@objtype = 'COLUMN'
```

**Option 3:** If the above also fails then you can try to create a new table with all the names correct and copy the data from the existing table to the new table and drop the previous one. And finally rename the table.

**EDIT:**

**Option 4:** As Gordon has said in comments, you might also want to check for schema.

```
EXEC sp_rename 
@objname = '[dbo].TBL_TAXREPORTtestxxx."[InsertedOn]"',   
@newname = 'InsertedOn', 
@objtype = 'COLUMN'
```